# How can I highlight search results live with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, search, replace, highlight

I am trying to find a way to highlight search results live as the user enters a search term into the input field. The target of the search is an unordered list. I am trying to use regex to highlight matches, but when I try to replace the results with a highlighted version of themselves I get an Undefined TypeError:

```
"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')"
```

I know that the error is in the last line of the displayMatches function but I can't figure out the correct syntax. Would anyone be able to help?

Here's the HTML:

```
         <ul>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
            <li>item 3</li>
            <li>item 4</li>
            <li>item 5</li>
            <li>item 6</li>
            <li>item 7</li>
            <li>item 8</li>
            <li>item 9</li>
           <li>item 10</li>
        </ul>
      
     
        <input id="search" type="text">
```

JavaScript:

```
let searchBar = document.getElementById("search");

const displayMatches = () => {
let userInput = document.getElementById("search").value;
let target = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
let regex = new RegExp(`${userInput}`, 'g');
target.innerHTML = target.innerText.replace(regex, match => `<mark>${match}</mark>`);
}

searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', displayMatches);
```

Comment: getElementsByTagName is an HTML collection!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is `target.innerHTML` and `target.innerText`

You got `target` from `document.getElementsByTagName("li")`. This statement returns an array of all of your `li` elements. But the `innerHTML` and the `innerText` propertys can't handle arrays, they just can handle single elements, so you have to loop through your `li`s:

```
for (i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
    target[i].innerHTML = target[i].innerText.replace(regex, match => `<mark>${match}</mark>`);
}
```

Comment: Just one thing, if - and only if - my answer helped you, could you accept it as best answer, please?